# Replace element in string issue

Tags: c

Here is my code

```
 int i;
    char new[SIZE_OF_ARRAY];
    printf("Which line would you like to replace?\n");
    scanf("%d", &i);

    if(i >= row)
    {
        printf("ROW SIZE CROSSED....RETURNNG BACK TO MAIN MENU");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("What would you like to be replace?\n");
        scanf("%[^\n]", new);

        strcpy(array[i],new);
    }

    return;
```

But when I run it, the scanf didn't work. It just skip the task...What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Try adding a \n to the first scanf

Comment: I added \n in front of scanf("%[^\n]", new);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it's because there is an newline character in the input buffer after `scanf("%d", &i);`, so then when you try to obtain something using `scanf("%[^\n]", new);` nothing's read because of the newline.

To verify it, print the return value of the 2nd `scanf` to see.

Solution: simply using `fgets` to do your 2nd `scanf`'s work, or consumes the newline before the 2nd `scanf`, e.g. changing the 1st `scanf` to `scanf("%d\n", &i);`

Comment: this is working, but what I did is I added \n in front of scanf("%[^\n]", new);

Comment: @kybookie That also consumes the newline so it's expected to work. :)

Comment: How do you actually 'eat' the newline.  your suggestion of \n in first scanf doesn't work for me.

Comment: @arcomber Hi what exactly your code? In this case it works, but I don't know what're your codes.

Comment: @starrify Same as asker but 1st scanf: scanf("%d", &i);  Using VS2008 newline just gets 'stuck'.

Answer (score 0):

scanf("%[^\n]", new);

strcpy(array[i],new);

--- I've never seen new keyword use in the second argument. Are you sure that's what you want?